# Aligning non-identical cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, vba

I have a question regarding aligning of two columns in Excel.

My first column (A) comprises of ~1000 emails, each one in its own cell, in alphabetical order.

My second column (B) consists of emails, ~900 of them, each in its own cell, in alphabetical order. All emails contained in the second column are also on the first, but there are ~100 from the first column that do not appear on the second. I would like to align the emails of the second column, so that each of them aligns with the original email in the first column.

Given that the cells are never completely identical due to special formatting at the end of each email in the second column, is there any way to align each 2nd column cell to the 1st column one?

Please see the link below for clarification and format of the second column.

(http://postimg.org/image/qvolipazb/)

Comment: It looks almost exactly the same as a question asked 3 hours ago by another new SO user with just one question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809369/aligning-two-columns-with-partial-matches-in-excel

Comment: I tried the match, but it doesn't align them, just returns an integer. Same project btw

Comment: @user3616725, one project, two posters, and not a single line of code or sign of effort between them. Hmm, must be one of those trendy modern schools.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with vlookup.

1. insert an extra column which will take just the email address out of
   your col B
2. populate with a function such as =LEFT(b8,FIND(",",b8)-1)
3. Use this as an index for vlookup